# Crop and resize image to fit a5 pdf

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation

I have an image (png, size 4288x2848) that I want to fit in a landscape a5 pdf with a 1cm border.

I know I can do it with `ImageMagick` but don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A5` landscape size is `210mmx148mm`.
With a `1cm` border (i.e. `10mm`) that means the image should be `200mm` wide and `138mm` high hence an aspect ratio of `1.45` - and your original image (`4288x2848`) is slightly wider: `1.51` aspect ratio. You'll have to crop it first to `4130x2848` so as to have the same aspect ratio.
You could do that by simply using `-extent` e.g.

```
convert in.png -extent 4130x2848 out.png
```

will crop the image to the desired size leaving the top left corner unaffected
 or you could instead [crop relative to gravity](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_gravity) e.g. *center*:

```
convert in.png -gravity center -crop 4130x2848+0+0 +repage out.png
```

whichever suits you better...
Once you have the cropped image you can convert it to `pdf`; for a page size `A5`  e.g. @ `300px` per inch (which is equivalent to `118px` per cm) the size of the canvas is `2480x1748` however if you subtract the `10mm` border which is `118px` your image should be `2362x1630` and the remaining  is the white background so again, with the help of `-extent`:

```
convert out.png -resize 2362x1630 -background white -gravity center -extent 2480x1748 out.pdf
```

Comment: This is great. Question: would it be too hard to add a border to the image instead of the white one?

Comment: I was thinking more of a line border or frame, in the white zone.

Comment: Thanks, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362269/border-with-imagemagick