# Border with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

In [Crop and resize image to fit a5 pdf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361317/crop-and-resize-image-to-fit-a5-pdf) I asked how to fit an image in a landscape A5.

Now I'd like to add a border or frame for the image and a tagline in the bottom (between the bottom line and the image).

Is this possible using ImageMagikc?

Comment: Types of borders I'm thinking of: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmI9O.jpg, https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeNfO.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqrfN.png

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with the help of the [`-draw`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/) operator:

```
convert in.png -fill none -stroke black -strokewidth ${WIDTH} -draw "rectangle ${X1},${Y1} ${X2},${Y2}" out.png
```

where:
`WIDTH` - stroke width
`X1` - x coordinate of the top left corner
`Y1` - y coordinate of the top left corner
`X2` - x coordinate of the bottom right corner
`Y2` - y coordinate of the bottom right corner

So e.g. for your other image that you want to crop+resize+convert to PDF you could run:

```
convert out.png -resize 2362x1630 -background white -gravity center -extent 2480x1748 \
-fill none -stroke black -strokewidth 10 -draw "rectangle 20,20 2460,1728" out.pdf
```